# ggplot2: normal distribution curve at bottom of graph - geom_text() + geom_historigram()

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to add a normal distribution line to my chart. But it simply becomes flat at the bottom for some reason.

My code

```
MyChart  <- function(x) {

  ggplot(x, aes( x = max.DrawD, y = cum.Return, label = Symbol)) +
    scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(seq(0, 10, 1)), limits = c(0,10)) + # outliers excluded
    scale_x_continuous(limit =c(0, 0.5)) +
    geom_histogram(aes(y = ..density..), binwidth = 0.02) +
    geom_text(size = 3) +
    stat_function(fun = dnorm, colour = 'firebrick') +
    theme_classic()
}
```

[image]

As you can see, the red line (my `stat_function()` code) is right at the bottom of the graph. How can I resolve this?

Comment: Thank you for the info! Will add as answer when that becomes available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE: So I solved it. But I don't know why it now works. Just added a manual spec on the mean and standard deviation.

Updated code

```
MyChart  <- function(x) {

  ggplot(x, aes( x = max.DrawD, y = cum.Return, label = Symbol)) +
    scale_y_continuous(breaks = c(seq(0, 10, 1)), limits = c(0,10)) + # outliers excluded
    scale_x_continuous(limit =c(0, 0.5)) +
    geom_histogram(aes(y = ..density..), binwidth = 0.02) +
    geom_text(size = 3) +
    stat_function(fun = dnorm, args = list(mean = mean(x$max.DrawD), sd = sd(x$max.DrawD)), colour = 'firebrick') +
    theme_classic()
}
```

From @user20650: it works as the function dnorm needs parameters mean and sd. If you dont specify them they are assumed to be zero and one